# java gkpluginslib security error

Tags: java, security, certificate, gkplugin

I'm in a big trouble. I get this popup when I want to run a video player on my page. I've google a lot and the reason should be the self signed certificate. I've never bought any ceritificate, or never installed. I've just read not all certificate is trusted to solve this, but I'm looking for the cheepest one, that can solve this, and I can use again this library without any popups.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/trhGB.png

The other questions is what should I do with the certificate? Where to put it, or how to insert to the site?

Thanks for the reply